# How to do something equivalent to "when, thenReturn" when you are testing a non-repository method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm writing some test code in Spring Boot JUnit, and was successful in a testing case with a repository method, using `"when, thenReturn"` like below.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) 
@WebMvcTest 
public class PictionarizerapiUserControllerTests {
    
  @MockBean 
  private UserRepository userRepository;
  
  @MockBean
  private UserController userController;
  
  @Autowired 
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Test
  @DisplayName("When an update request is sent, the User data gets updated properly, and the updated User data gets returned in a form of JSON")
  public void testUpdateUser() throws Exception {
    // User before update
    User existingUser = new User();
    existingUser.setId(28);
    existingUser.setName("Alex");
    ......
    ......
    
    // return the User (before update) that is fetched by UserRepository#findById() with ID=28
    when(userRepository.findById(28)).thenReturn(Optional.of(existingUser));
    // UserRepository#save() returns the fetched entity as it is
    when(userRepository.save(any())).thenAnswer((invocation) -> invocation.getArguments()[0]);
    ......
    ......
```

I thought I could also write a test case for a controller method which I wrote myself, and I tried to do "when, thenReturn" as the following.

```
@Test
  @DisplayName("When correct login information is given and the matched user is fetched")
  public void testCheckIfValidUserFound() throws Exception {
      Integer userIdObj = Integer.valueOf(28);
      
      String requestEmail = "alex.armstrong@example.com";
      String requestPassword = "MajorStateAlchemist";
      
      when(userController.checkIfValidUser(requestEmail, requestPassword)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userIdObj));

      ......
      ......
  }
```

However, I got an error message `The method thenReturn(ResponseEntity<capture#1-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<ResponseEntity<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Integer>)`. I did some research and came to the understanding that you can use `"when, thenReturn"` syntax only when you are testing repository methods, which are built in methods in JPA, like `findById()` etc (unless I'm mistaken), and in my case it doesn't work because what I'm trying to test is a method that I created on my own, not a JPA's built in repository method.

And here comes my question.
How can I write something that is equivalent to `"when, thenReturn"` when I'm testing something other than a repository method?

**UPDATE**

This is how my own method is defined.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkIfValidUser(
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("password") String password) {  
        int userId = 0;
        
        List<User> userList = repository.findAll();
        
        for(User user: userList) {
            String userEmail = user.getEmail();
            String userPassword = user.getPassword();
            String inputEmail = email;
            String inputPassword = password;
            if(userEmail.equals(inputEmail) && userPassword.equals(inputPassword)) {
                userId = user.getId();
            }
        }   
        
        if(userId > 0) {
            Integer userIdObj = Integer.valueOf(userId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userIdObj, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new Error("The email address and the password don't match"),  
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*I did some research and came to the understanding that you can use "when, thenReturn" syntax only when you are testing repository methods, which are built in methods in JPA*" - Can you link the source? In general, one can verify all calls on mocks. --- The error message suggests that `userController.checkIfValidUser(...)` does return something different than a `Optional<Integer>`. Method name suggests maybe a `boolean`?

Comment: How is `checkIfValidUser` defined?

Comment: @Turing I'm afraid I don't remember the link. Regarding that "you can use "when, thenReturn" syntax only works when..." statement, it's just my hypothesis and I'm not fully certain if it's correct (that's why I added (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: @luk2302 I updated my original post and now you can see how ```checkIfValidUser``` is defined.

Comment: And you can see that it returns a `ResponseEntity<?>`, not a `Optional<Integer>`, the types have to match.

Comment: I see. I tried to replace the part ```Integer userIdObj = Integer.valueOf(28);``` with ```ResponseEntity<?> loginEntity = new ResponseEntity<?>();```, but couldn't instantiate it. What is a bit tricky about this is the type (the ? part) of ResponseEntity<?> is not completely decided until the method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that the method that you want to test is `testCheckIfValidUserFound()`, you shouldn't mock the method itself like so.

```
when(userController.checkIfValidUser(requestEmail, requestPassword)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userIdObj));
```

Instead, the method that you are supposed to mock is `userRepository.findAll()` because that's the repository method that you are calling inside the `checkIfValidUser` method in your controller.

So your "when, thenReturn" part should look like this.

```
when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(esixtingUser));
```

and when you want to check if the test returns the correct value, ordinarily you need to specify which key's value you want to check, but in this case, according to your `checkIfValidUser` method it just returns an integer if the search is successful, so there shouldn't be any specification along with the dollar sign when asserting with `jsonPath`.

So after you mock the repository you can perform a get request like so.

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/login")
    .param("email", requestEmail)
    .param("password", requestPassword)
    .with(request -> {
      request.setMethod("GET")<
      return request;
    }))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$").value(28));
```